# Why does Shiny reactiveValues() is not change as expected?

Tags: r, logout, shiny

I have declared an R `Shiny` code in:

```
################# Security Login, part of server.R in R Shiny App
USER <- reactiveValues()
USER$Logged <- FALSE

## Some logic for login which changes USER$Logged to TRUE, eg. USER$Logged <- TRUE, this works well in changing to TRUE

## Logout handler fails because it can change to FALSE, but then resets back to TRUE
logoutHandler <- observeEvent(input$Logout,
  USER$Logged <- FALSE
}

#This is the trace result.  The number 1 or 0 is the value of input$Logout
#"USER$Logged:  FALSE 1"
#"USER$Logged outside Handler:  FALSE 1"
#"USER$Logged outside Handler:  TRUE 1" #Proof of reset
#"USER$Logged outside Handler:  TRUE 0" #Proof of reset
```

At the end the code will not be working anymore.  Connection reset happens or nothing happen just resets back to TRUE and discards the FALSE assignment.

How to fix this?

Comment: at the end of what code?  shiny apps are designed to run indefinetly until interrupted

Comment: Can you run your logout function when the user closes the app? If so have a look at `session$onEnded()`

Comment: I'm thinking of setting `USER$Logged <- FALSE` to invalidate the login.  I have some logic that checks for USER$Logged.  Example line: `if (USER$Logged == TRUE){ ...some code...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error, this code works for me so the error might be in some of your other server logic.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  actionButton('btn','go')
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  a <- reactiveValues(l=FALSE)
  b <- reactiveValues()
  b$l <- FALSE

  observe({
    print(sprintf('Outisde, A: %s, B: %s',a$l,b$l))
  })

  observeEvent(input$btn,{
    print(sprintf('Inside [before], A: %s, B: %s',a$l,b$l))

    a$l <- TRUE
    b$l <- TRUE

    print(sprintf('Inside [after], A: %s, B: %s',a$l,b$l))
  })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Thank you. @oskar-forsmo I tried to test with a stop button and it worked. I'll be checking other logic and might test other parts of the code.

Comment: I'll update when I found which resets value to TRUE again just after `USER$Logged <- FALSE`.

Comment: Sounds good, may I ask why you are saving the observer reference class from observeEvent to a variable? if you want to use it as a reactive have a look at `eventReactive`. Anyway hope you solve this!

Comment: Thank you very much. I've found out the culprit.  The reason why this does not work is because the logic is in a `renderText`, so I removed the code from there and then create a separate `observeEvent` for the button.